# Raspberry Pi OGLES setup

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0, raspberry-pi2

A very easy/hard question. 
What packages do i need to download to be able to create a simple X11 window with an EGL/OpenGLES contex.
As i have today the the problem with dri2 failing to authenticate.
But it can’t be that i link to the wrong library else it wouldn’t accept the X11 window at all at eglGetDisplay.

- I really don’t want to use any library like glfw or sdl (wrapper
  wrapper).
- I use raspbian stretch with the default full KMS(driver by VMWare).

My Code is(if it matter's):

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglplatform.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Pane {
    Window win;
    Display *display;
    Atom windowDeletMessage;
    int x11_file;

    EGLDisplay egl_display;
    EGLContext egl_context;
    EGLSurface egl_surface;
    EGLConfig  egl_config;
    EGLint     egl_num_config;

    EGLint egl_minor;
    EGLint egl_major;
};

void setup_window(Pane &self) {

    self.display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    if (self.display == nullptr) {
        exit(0);
    }

    auto s = DefaultScreen(self.display);
    self.win = XCreateSimpleWindow(self.display,
                                   RootWindow(self.display, s),
                                   10,
                                   10,
                                   800,
                                   600,
                                   1,
                                   BlackPixel(self.display, s),
                                   WhitePixel(self.display, s));

    self.windowDeletMessage = XInternAtom(self.display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", false);
    XSetWMProtocols(self.display, self.win, &self.windowDeletMessage, 1);

    XStoreName(self.display, self.win, "Default Window");

    XSelectInput(self.display,self.win, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | LeaveWindowMask | EnterWindowMask | PointerMotionMask | ResizeRedirectMask);

    XMapWindow(self.display, self.win);
    XFlush(self.display);

    self.x11_file = ConnectionNumber(self.display);
}

void GetEvent(Pane &self, XEvent &e) {
    // Event handling...
}

void setup_egl(Pane &self)
{
    const EGLint Attributes[] = //Note to much is to much
    {
            EGL_RED_SIZE,8,
            EGL_GREEN_SIZE,8,
            EGL_BLUE_SIZE,8,
            EGL_ALPHA_SIZE,8,
            EGL_NONE,
    };

    self.egl_display = eglGetDisplay(self.display);
    if(self.egl_display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
    {
        printf("EGL Failed to Obtain Window!")  // Note this is not Error handling!
               exit(103);
    }
    if(eglInitialize(self.egl_display,&self.egl_major,&self.egl_minor) == EGL_FALSE)
    {
        printf("EGL Failed to Initzialize!""");
        exit(104);
    };

    eglChooseConfig(self.egl_display, Attributes, &self.egl_config, 1, &self.egl_num_config);
    self.egl_context = eglCreateContext(self.egl_display, self.egl_config,EGL_NO_CONTEXT,nullptr);
    self.egl_surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(self.egl_display, self.egl_config, self.win, nullptr);
    eglMakeCurrent(self.egl_display, self.egl_surface, self.egl_surface, self.egl_context);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
    eglSwapBuffers(self.display, self.egl_surface);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Pane pane;
    setup_window(pane);
    setup_egl(pane);

    XEvent e;
    while (true) {
        GetEvent(pane, e);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

As i used an USB-Drive to boot and not the SD Card. So raspi-config couldn't access the config file on the SD Card and a such it could not enable full KMS.

Comment: What is your work environment?

Comment: For this project i used windows with vs2017 and i use the default gcc via remote build.